# r line plot y axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a line plot and here is my code and dataset used to produce this plot.

```
ggplot(testdf , aes(measurement, Month)) +
geom_line(aes(group = Month)) +
geom_point(aes(color = Year))

testdf <- structure(list(Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10, 11, 12), Year = c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014), measurement = c(0.615151515, 
0.59116161625, 0.609090909, 0.613131313, 0.621212121, 0.63964646425, 
0.619191919, 0.634343434, 0.645454545, 0.676767677, 0.6368686865, 
0.6459595955, 0.656565657, 0.623232323, 0.638383838, 0.6358585855, 
0.651515152, 0.6772727275, 0.675757576, 0.666666667, 0.6964646465, 
0.704040404, 0.6843434345, 0.673737374, 0.6792929295, 0.63813131275, 
0.6641414145, 0.65782828325, 0.6712121215, 0.709090909, 0.7136363635, 
0.686868687, 0.708080808, 0.724242424, 0.7015151515, 0.7237373735
)), .Names = c("Month", "Year", "measurement"), row.names = c(NA, 
-36L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Month", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    c(0L, 12L, 24L), c(1L, 13L, 25L), c(2L, 14L, 26L), c(3L, 
    15L, 27L), c(4L, 16L, 28L), c(5L, 17L, 29L), c(6L, 18L, 30L
    ), c(7L, 19L, 31L), c(8L, 20L, 32L), c(9L, 21L, 33L), c(10L, 
    22L, 34L), c(11L, 23L, 35L)), group_sizes = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), biggest_group_size = 3L, labels = structure(list(
    Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Month", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Month"))
```

[image]

The issue is the y axis labels. How do I change the y axis labels such that it shows labels like, 1-Jan, 2-Feb, 3-March instead of 2.5, 5, 7.5 etc.. Any advise on how to change the y axis labels is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ggplot2` and `lubridate`, you could do the following:

```
library(ggplot2)

testdf$Month <- lubridate::month(testdf$Month, label = TRUE)

ggplot(testdf, aes(measurement, Month)) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Month)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Year))
```

[image]

And if you don't want the months to be abbreviated, you can modify the `lubridate` line with `abbr = FALSE`:

```
lubridate::month(testdf$Month, label = TRUE, abbr = FALSE)
```

Comment: that is exactly what the doctor ordered :-), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First line is based on answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39423556/5333994

```
testdf <- within(testdf, Date <- sprintf("%d-%02d-01", Year, Month))

ggplot(testdf , aes(measurement, as.Date(Date, "%Y-%m-%d"))) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Month)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Year)) +
  scale_y_date()
```

[image]